# Eclipse: CSS file considered as XML by mistake

Tags: css, xml, eclipse, editor, eclipse-oxygen

Every time I create a CSS file, eclipse creates an XML file instead. So it does not provide me the autocompletion of the attributes since it considers it as an XML file and not a CSS file without forgetting the annoying warnings.

The picture below shows how the extension is `.css` but the file type is XML create by *New > Other...: CSS File*. I tried also to create the file manually:

[image: ------ THE PICTURE --------]

Comment: Right-click a `.css` file and choose _Open With > Others..._, select the CSS editor, check _Use it for all '.css' files_ and click _OK_.

Comment: What CSS and XML editors are involved here? Did you previously try to open a .css file with an XML editor?